# Enable/Disable WebView In another activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to implement WebView in a such way that it should get instantiated in one Activity (along with loading of html) it should not be visible on first page and only webview is visible in another activity. I have tried following way, but unable to achieve it, following is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView = null;
    private Button startAppBtn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createWebView();

        startAppBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        startAppBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    intent.putExtra("state",bundle);
                    webView.saveState(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void createWebView(){
        setWebView((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1)); 
        getWebView().getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getWebView().getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        getWebView().getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        getWebView().setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        getWebView().setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);      
        getWebView().loadUrl("file:///android_asset/My.html");
        getWebView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public WebView getWebView() {
        return webView;
    }

    public void setWebView(WebView webView) {
        this.webView = webView;
    }
}
```

and following is SecondActivity,

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);//at this line I am getting exception, I think because webview is in activity_main layout.
        webview.restoreState((Bundle) intent.getParcelableExtra("state"));
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I am new to android world, struggling on it please anybody can help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

First Activity

```
    startAppBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    startAppBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("websiteURL", "file:///android_asset/My.html");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Second Activity

```
    String sWebsite;
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        sWebsite = bundle.getString("websiteURL");
    }
    else if (bundle== null)
    {
        System.out.println("Null");
    }

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(sWebsite);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```